# Heroku Local Error Output

Tags: node.js, heroku, error-handling, foreman

When running a NodeJS app locally with heroku (heroku local), any errors encountered are only marked with the relevant filename with no verbose output.

This makes local builds very difficult to troubleshoot and I'm struggling to find any information on how to get verbose error reporting.

```
forego | starting web.1 on port 5000
web.1  | module.js:339 < appears in red on error
```

NOTE: The task runner is foreman.

Can someone suggest a method of getting verbose error output when using heroku local?